# Set security for Process object in java

Tags: java, security, web-applications

Can some one tell how can I restrict System properties to be accessed through a process object? If I run the following piece of code through process object , can I throw security exceptions.

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Please enlighten me about how to configure the securities for a process object.

In ProcessBuilder class document , in environment method it is written:

> A system may not allow modifications to environment variables or may
>   forbid certain variable names or values.

So please let me know how to forbid certain variable values.

**Updated:**
So suppose I am using a Java web application and giving the client side a platform to code. Then how to configure the java security separately for java web application and for client side application.(As I will never want to restrict the web application to get any property of System, whereas I must restrict client side to use these commands for application vulnerability)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own security manager and check access for some properties

```
public class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

@Override
public void checkPropertyAccess(String key) throws SecurityException  {
        if ( key != null && key.equals("some.forbidden_value") {
            throw new SecurityException("some message");
         }
         super.checkPropertyAccess( key );
    }
}
```

And somewhere else in your code attach your security manager:

```
System.setSecurityManager( new MySecurityManager() );
```

Comment: Lots of thanks. Its working just like I wanted. But can you please elaborate your answer. It would be a great help @StephaneM

Comment: Can I add this security to a Process class object ?

Comment: I don't know. If you want to implement a policy in a child process, you might want to use a policy file instead of doing it programmatically. See there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

Comment: Please check this question if u can help, its a related question of this @StephaneM 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467866/pro-grade-library-for-java-security-and-permission